# Angular 7: Display images of product inside a loop using s3 key not working

Tags: angular, image, amazon-s3, sanitization

I am calling a function to fetch the URL from the s3 bucket by passing the key.
The function works fine, I get the URL of the image but I am not able to display it on HTML

HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let i of data">
    <img [src]="getImage(i.key)" />
</div>
```

component code

```
getImage(key: string) {    
    var awsConfig = new AWS.Config({
      accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      region: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    });
    const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsConfig);

      const urlParams = {
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        Key: key,
      };
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, (err, url) => {          
          if (err) reject(err)
          else resolve(url);
          return url;                    
        });
      });    
  }
```

Comment: your method getImage is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to return url value from your function getImage()

```
getImage(key: string) {    
var awsConfig = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  region: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsConfig);

  const urlParams = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Key: key,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, (err, url) => {          
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(url);                    
    });
  });    


}
```

Comment: I forgot to return the result in the above code but it's present in the code. It's still not working.